# Limit find the value of $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

If $\alpha$ $in$ $\mathbb{R}$, differrent of 1. Consider this sucession $x_{n}$ = $\frac{\alpha \cdot n^{2}-1}{(\alpha-1)n^{2} + 1}$. Find the value of $\alpha$, if $x_n$ convergent to $\alpha$ when n tends to infinity.

My question is: i solving this exercise, i obteind two possible values of $\alpha$= 0 or 2, but the problem is what's next step of consider write for find the limit,because i have a theorem what mentioned: the limit of succesion is unique.

Thanks You, for all suggested.

Comment: You may check if your question is posted correctly.. We can take limits as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and it leads to the limit value $x = {\alpha \over \alpha - 1}$. We don't understand your statement "when x tends to infinity". What is $x$ here?

Comment: Yes is correct, is n, not x. thanks
Is my mistake.

Comment: I gave a detailed solution considering many cases for $\alpha$. When $\alpha = 1$, the sequence diverges, and I gave a general formula for the limit for the other cases.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of a sequence, if it exists, is indeed unique. Your solution is correct, and there is no problem because for each possible value of $\alpha$ that you found, you get a different sequence. For $\alpha=0$ you get the sequence $-\frac{1}{1-n^2}$, whose (unique!) limit is zero, and for $\alpha=2$ you get the sequence $\frac{2n^2-1}{n^2+1}$, whose (unique!) limit is $2$. All is well.

Comment: Thanks you, so much

Answer (score 0):

Given that
$$
x_n = {\alpha n^2 - 1 \over (\alpha - 1) n^2 + 1} \tag{1}
$$

First, we compute the limit $L = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ x_n$
directly.

We can express (1) as
$$
x_n = {\alpha - (1/n^2) \over (\alpha - 1) + (1/n^2)} \tag{2}
$$

Taking limits as $n \rightarrow \infty$ in (2), we get
$$
L = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ x_n = {\alpha \over \alpha - 1}
$$

This is a general result for all values $\alpha \neq 1$, $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$.

As a special case, if we take $\alpha = 0$, then
$$
L =  {\alpha \over \alpha - 1} = {0 \over 0 - 1} = 0
$$

When $\alpha = 2$, then
$$
L =  {\alpha \over \alpha - 1} = {2 \over 2 - 1} = 2
$$

I hope that my calculations help you to understand the limit of the given sequence $\{ x_n \}$ for various values of $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$.

When $\alpha = 1$, we have
$$
x_n = n^2
$$
which obviously diverges when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thanks You, so much